# Using Backendless API with Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt, backendless

I'm writing an application on Qt Android (C++) ,  and would like to manage some data and users on Backendless server. 
How can i use their APIs? 
Is the REST the only way in this case?

Comment: Yeah. See the [doc](https://backendless.com/products/documentation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently there is no SDK for C or C++, so your only option is to use [REST SDK](https://backendless.com/mobile-developers/quick-start-guide-for-rest-api/).